# Show DropDownList that is created by codebehind in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a list of **DropDownList** using code behind .

```
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DropDownList> i=new List<DropDownList>();
        DropDownList o1=new DropDownList();
        i.Add(o1);
    }
```

So i create a object **o1** .so my problem is how can i show it in my page (i.e default.aspx)

```
                        <div class="columns-score" style="float:left">
                            <span style="color:#ea0000;padding:0 10px;">
                                ---i want to show DDl here 
                            </span>
                        </div>
```

I use **response.write(O1)** but it was wrong .so what should i do ?

Comment: There is no response.write in your code. And you don't really ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="columns-score" style="float: left">
   <span style="color: #ea0000; padding: 0 10px;" id="ddlSpan" runat="server"></span>
</div>
```

Code-behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        DropDownList o1 = new DropDownList();
        o1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Text1","Value1"));
        o1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Text2","Value2"));
        ddlSpan.Controls.Add(o1);
    }
```

Comment: @SSC `o1` will be added to the list of controls in `ddlSpan`, thus causing it to show on your page.

Comment: ddlSpan.Controls.Add(o1) adds the dropdownlist control to the span tag in your page.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add that dropdown to some html element with `runat server attribute`

or a `panel`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    DropDownList o1 = new DropDownList();
    o1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Text1","Value1"));
    o1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Text2","Value2"));
    testdiv.Controls.Add(o1);
}
```